# Special char at index.html in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to put two text this way in my index.html:

```
<div style="margin-top:50px" class="text-right">
  Version: <b>${display_version}</b> - Release:<b>${buildNumber}</b>
</div>
```

But when I execute my app I receive the error message:

```
Template execution failed: ReferenceError: buildNumber is not defined
    ReferenceError: buildNumber is not defined
  - index.html:4 eval
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:4:10
  - index.html:7 module.exports
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:7:3
  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
    [cotador-vida-global-frontend]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18
  - next_tick.js:189 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7
```

How to put this sentence (`${display_version} / ${buildNumber}`) in vuejs?

Comment: `buildNumber` is not defined in the context. Are you sure it's not `build_number`?

Comment: Yes, I want to write the sentences: ${buildVersion} and ${display_version}, they are not defined in any place. But i don't how to escape this sentences in vuejs compiler.

Comment: have you tried using v-html?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you have to initalize those variables.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    display_version:"",
    buildNumber: ""
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div style="margin-top:50px" class="text-right">
    Version: <b>{{display_version}}</b> - Release:<b>{{buildNumber}}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```